# virtualbox installing iso Error "could not find a valid v7 on sda"

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox, android

I decided to try [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6058689/463994) to install Android x86 on Virtual Box. I'm following those steps and I'm at #4. I used the [android-x86-4.0-RC1-amd_brazos.iso](http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-4.0-RC1-amd_brazos.iso&can=2&q=) (because I have a ThinkPad that this might be compatible with and it seemed as good as any of the other choices...)

I'm getting an endless series of errors:

```
.[numbers] VFS: could not find a valid v7 on sda.
.[numbers] VFS: could not find a valid v7 on sda.
repeating...
```

For storage, I made a VDI image sized at 4.0 GB (dynamically allocated) attached on SATA Port 0.

**Background and more details:**

I'm running Kubuntu 12.04. I [installed VirtualBox 4.1.12](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66765/how-do-i-install-virtualbox-4-1) after adding `deb http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian precise contrib` to my sources.

EDIT: Now I'm wondering if I installed the right package. I verified that I'm running 4.1.12. But I installed it with `apt-get install virtualbox` instead of the recommended `apt-get install virtualbox-4.1`. I checked just now and see this:

```
apt-cache search virtualbox
virtualbox - x86 virtualization solution - base binaries
virtualbox-4.1 - Oracle VM VirtualBox
```

But when I run VirtualBox, I get the Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager version 4.1.12, so I think I'm OK.

I did see one minor issue ([possibly related to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49059/unable-to-install-virtualbox-due-to-missing-kernel-module)) when installing VB, but in my case I don't think it is actually an error at all:

```
* No suitable module for running kernel found [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

VirtualBox installed and seems to be running fine. I just can't get the ISO image to install. The error is as shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed a different image:
[android-x86-4.0-RC1-asus_laptop.iso](http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=android-x86-4.0-RC1-asus_laptop.iso&can=2&q=)

It worked. I'm not sure if the brazos image incompatible with the VM I set up or there was some other issue. But it is working with this image.